# What determines military aviation squadron numbers?

Tags: military

What determines the numbers and the names of squadrons, airwings, and other military aviation units? Does it go in order of when they were established?

Comment: Many factors are involved, that create little rhyme or reason.  Much of the influence is historical.  If the Army signal corps 123 battalion was transformed to become an Army Air Corps Battalion in, say, WWI, then that might also later become the 123 Fighter Wing years later.  Also, the Army went through a period in WWII where there were categories that drove numbers that were thus out of sequence.  For instance, for a time, airborne units were all given 5xx designations (like the 509th PIR) even if the sequential numbers were only up to say 300.  So it's a giant "it depends" non-answer.

Comment: Tradition. History. Phase of the moon. How hungover the general was that day. Who knows. :)